# CSS: How do I centre an element relative to its parent while right-aligning its sibling?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have made a rough sketch of what I would like to do: 
[image]

I am using a Bootstrap list group. In the uppermost `li`, I have some text in an `h4` element and a glyph in a `span` element. I would like to centre the `h4` relative to its parent `li` (i.e. not taking the `span` into account, along A in the sketch) and right-align the `span` at the same height as the `h4` (along B in the sketch).

I have looked for possible solutions, but I can't seem to find one that works in my particular situation. The elements are either not horizontally aligned or the `h4` is centred only within itself (i.e. it takes the `span` into account).

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3vdvtxj/1/

Comment: You should post a fiddle with some markup and styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **relative** and **absolute** position and `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to center it vertically and horizontally, also add `text-right` class to first `li` to pull span to right side.

```css
li:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

li:first-child p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item text-right">
    <p>Cras justo odio</p>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Fantastic! I appreciate it very much!

Comment: I'm glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you will do something like this:

```css
ul.list {
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
 }
ul.list li {
  width:100%;
  padding:20px 0;
  background:yellow;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  }
ul.list h4 {
  text-align:center;
  }
ul.list span {
  float:right;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <span>right align me</span>
    <h4>title goes here</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>right align me</span>
    <h4>title goes here</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>right align me</span>
    <h4>title goes here</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>right align me</span>
    <h4>title goes here</h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code below.

In this way, you don't care about the order of your HTML tag into your li, and you have the possibility to center your text on y axis also.

```css
li:first-child {
  position: relative; /* First you create a reference for your h4 absolute item. */
  text-align: right; /* And you put the span to right. */
}
li:first-child span,
li:first-child h4 {
    text-align: left; /* You align content as you want. */
}
li:first-child h4 {
    /* And you X/Y center the h4 content with the `li` relavive reference. */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* The CSS below is not a part of the answer but help the result to be more nice. */
ul {
  width:100%; 
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li span {
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 20px;
   border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
li h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h4>A AAA AA AAA AA A AAAAA A </h4>
    <span>B</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>A AAA AA AAAAAA<br>AA A AAAAA<br>A AAA AA AAAAAA</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>A AAA AAAAA</h4>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4>A AAA AA<br>AA A AAAAA</h4>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you just want centered on x axis, use just `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)`.